# How to use GAE Service account to call Cloud Endpoints server-to-server?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, service-accounts

We are using Google Cloud Endpoints (GCE) extensively in our microservice-oriented architecture. All services are Google App Engine. For public-facing GAE services, we will use the standard Android OAuth to authenticate real users. However, for non-user-facing services, we want our Cloud Endpoints to be secured (not publicly available), but accessible by the default GAE service account.

For example, the internal Payment Service might want to contact the internal User Service to fetch a user's profile, authenticating with the default GAE service account so we don't need to embed any credentials in our code. We are using the generated Java libs.

I'm using code like this to initialize the service with the generated libs:

```
public User createUserService() {    
    AppIdentityCredential credential = new AppIdentityCredential(Lists.newArrayList(OAUTH_EMAIL_SCOPE))
    return new User.Builder(new UrlFetchTransport(), new JacksonFactory, credential)
        .setRootUrl(userServiceRootUrl)
        .build()
}
```

We *also* tried using the *GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault()* and setting scopes on that credential object.

The target endpoint that's being called from the first GAE service has code like this:

```
@Api(
  name      = "user",
  version   = "v1",
  clientIds = Array(Constants.APP_ENGINE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_ID)
)
class UserEndpoints {
  /**
    * GET /user/:id
    *
    * Get a single user by id
    */
  @ApiMethod(
    httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET,
    path = "user/{id}"
  )
  def find(
    @Named("id") id: Long,
    authUser: GoogleUser
  ): User = {
    if (authUser == null) {
      throw new OAuthRequestException("Must be authenticated to use this endpoint!")
    }
    UserDAO.find(id) getOrElse  {
      throw new NotFoundException("User not found")
    }
  }
```

The client id used above is the one you can find in a JSON key file for GAE service accounts, which is displayed in the API Credentials console if you have added Domain-wide-delegation to your service account.

We also tried variations on this, like removing the User argument and instead setting *authLevel = AuthLevel.REQUIRED* on the @Api annotation.

No dice, we always get an error like this:

```
Request URL: https://user-service-dot-foo-dev.appspot.com/_ah/api/user/v1/user/1
Method: user.userEndpoints.find
Error Code: 403
Reason: insufficientAuthorizedParty
Message: Client_id is not allowed
```

Does anyone know -- what are we doing wrong? Why is it so difficult to have secured traffic with service accounts?

We want to avoid embedding credentials on our code, so please don't respond by saying we need to create a manual service account.

Thanks for any good suggestions! We are really surprised how difficult it is to do server-to-server communication with Cloud Endpoints!